# cannot find module in index.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

hi I have this error while trying to import components (im using flow type)

This is my ReloadScreenPayLater.component.js

```html
/**
 * Reload Screen Component
 * @param {Props} onReload - reload Parameter
 * @return {React.Node} - return react component
 */
const ReloadScreenPaylater = ({ onReload }: Props): React.Node => (
  <ReloadScreen onReload={onReload} />
);

ReloadScreenPaylater.displayName = config.displayName;

export default ReloadScreenPaylater;
```

this is my export in ./src/Components/ReloadScreenPayLater/index.js
when i highlight the export it shows the ReloadScreenPayLater.component.js
[image: it has the ReloadScreenPayLater]

so when i tried to run the apps or snap test it shows this error

```html
src/Screens/InOutPayLater/InOutPayLater.component.snap.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '../../Component/ReloadScreenPayLater' from 'src/Screens/InOutPayLater/InOutPayLater.component.snap.test.js'

      10 |   .mock('../../Components/InOutEmptyState', () => 'InOutEmptyState')
      11 | 
    > 12 |   .mock('../../Component/ReloadScreenPayLater', () => 'ReloadScreenPayLater');
```

what i want to achieve is to be able to import the component from this path '../../Component/ReloadScreenPayLater'

nb: it works just fine if import like this

```html
import ReloadScreenPaylater from '../../Components/ReloadScreenPayLater/ReloadScreenPayLater.component';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default export (i.e. `export default ReloadScreenPaylater = ...`), we should use this import style instead.

```
import ReloadScreenPaylater from '../../Components/ReloadScreenPayLater/ReloadScreenPayLater.component';
```

For named export (i.e. `export const ReloadScreenPaylater = ...`), then we should use the other named import style.

```
import { ReloadScreenPaylater } from '../../Components/ReloadScreenPayLater/ReloadScreenPayLater.component';
```

Answer (score 1):

From ES6 and onwards, you need to get the default exports from their name instead of {default}

Use this:

```
import ReloadScreenPaylater from '../../Components/ReloadScreenPayLater/ReloadScreenPayLater.component';
```

Or if you have named export then use `import { Exported Named Component } from 'path'`